# Import jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-import

I want to import 'jquery-validation' into an ES6 class

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'jquery-validation'
```

but when I do anywhere in the same file

```
$(...).validate({...})
```

I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
```

Comment: What method did you use to make your `import` statement available on the browser? I have a gulp `browserify` task with `babelify` transform that works just fine ( I have the same import statements you wrote above).
Check these references: https://github.com/babel/babelify, http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/05/25/browserify-babelify-and-es6.html

Answer (score 13):

From the looks of your code example you weren't importing it correctly. Works  for me with the following imports (with Webpack bundling):

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import validate from 'jquery-validation'
```

Comment: Though this works at a module, but how to use this on mine html page? It looks like unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import validate from "jquery-validation";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  function handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(ref.current).validate({
      rules: {
        name: { required: true },
        address: { required: true }
      },
      messages: {
        name: { required: "Name field is required" },
        address: { required: "Address field is required" }
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <form ref={ref} onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} noValidate="novalidate">
      <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
      <textarea
        name="address"
        id="address"
        cols="4"
        rows="4"
        placeholder="Address"
      ></textarea>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

And link https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-dirac-7h8t6?file=/src/App.js:0-873

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)